# Max Age property in Orchard CMS Cache settings

Tags: caching, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7, orchard-modules

What does the Max Age setting in Cache does ?

[image]

The default value used is 0 (zero). So this zero means is it enabled or disabled ? Which value will enable the Max Age and thus enable IIS Kernel Caching ?

Below is what the Orchard Documentation says about Max Age:
Using the Max Age setting you also enable IIS Kernel caching plus public proxy cache which makes your application even faster. You can get thousands of requests per seconds with a very small server.

Just wanted to understand what is meant by IIS Kernel caching and Public proxy cache ? What all Items/Objects do they cache ?

Answer (score 0):

max-age is a similar property for caching any website.

max-age=[seconds] — specifies the maximum amount of time that a representation will be considered fresh. Similar to Expires, this directive is relative to the time of the request, rather than absolute. [seconds] is the number of seconds from the time of the request you wish the representation to be fresh for.

Source: https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/